# Do BigCommerce webhooks work with URLs having non-standard SSL ports (i.e. 5443)

Tags: bigcommerce

We have created a webhook to post to a URL that uses a non-standard SSL port 5443.  The webhook posts to other endpoints/URLs, but doesn't come through to this one.  Do we need to use the standard port 443 for webhook to work?

Comment: erm, good question, try including the port in the URL you set for the webhook? `https://webhook_url.com:5443` See if that works, if not, then the answer would be no :(

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any answers so I decided to switch back to port 443 (standard SSL port) and everything works now.

BigCommerce, please update your documentation.

Comment: Just so others can know, did you try including the port number when you specified the URL? Meaning, you set the webhook url as `https://url.com/webhook:5443`?